# Exporting AI file to PSD - why do my layers merge?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, layers, export

I'm trying to export an AI file, which has a ton of sublayers under one layer and some groups and stuff. I've tried exporting to PSD, following the guidelines I've found online (Write Layers and whatever else ticked), but it keeps coming through as only a single layer. I'm not sure exactly what might be causing all of the layers to merge. May I get some assistance?

For reference, this is the Layers panel:

[image: layers]

Thanks

Comment: They arent layers... thats just the natute of vectpr graphics everything you do is an object. If you want to export layers then use main level layers.

Answer (score 2):

That screen shot of the Layers Panel shows **only ONE layer**. So, of course, if you export it you'll only get one layer in the export.

If you *want* multiple layers exported, the Illustrator file must have multiple layers.

The Layers Panel *in Illustrator* is *actually* more like a "layers and objects panel". It shows not only layers, but each object on that layer as well. *Objects* do not export as separate *layers*, because they aren't layers.

Answer (score 0):

When you export from Illustrator to PSD format, in export dialog in options section select write layers and maximum editability. Only compound paths exports as vector.

Comment: That's exactly what I've tried ('I've tried exporting to PSD following the guidelines... Write Layers and whatever else ticked')

Comment: maybe you have transparent objects that flatten all artwork when exporting

Answer (score 0):

You should ungroup everything first, and make sure not to use blending modes at all. Also set the color mode to RGB not the CMYK.

There you'd be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue all the time also. Sometimes it flattens everything - sometimes it separates. I think the above answer is most correct after just doing this. If you have any effect layers / opacity effects like multiply ect. I think you need to rasterise it first. I just did this - got about an 80% success rate out of each layer. It still never works 100%.

Comment: In this *particular question* the user only has **one layer** in Illustrator. That is why they are only seeing one layer in Photoshop. For issues with *actual* multi-layered AI files see here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25020/exporting-multi-layered-illustrator-to-photoshop The export is 100% predictable once you understand *why* AI layers may get merged.

Answer (score -3):

You have to rasterize the image made in illustrator

Save all your groups in different layers too.

Just do Control/CMD + A -> effects -> Rasterize

That happens because Photoshop doesn't deal with vector images so they have to be rasterized first!

Comment: Actually.. uhm.... no.